# Data Refinery Job failed with SCAPIException CDICO2060E

Tags: data-science-experience, watson-studio

I'm building my first project in Watson Studio and a  Data Refinery Job fails with the following error:

`ERROR: Failed to execute the flow. Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver): com.ibm.connect.api.SCAPIException: CDICO2060E: The metadata for the select statement could not be retrieved Sql syntax error: THE DATA TYPE, LENGTH, OR VALUE OF ARGUMENT 1 OF RID IS INVALID. SQLCODE=-171`

The SQL it's executing contains this: `FROM \"SCHEMA\".\"VIEW_NAME_A\" WHERE MOD(COALESCE(RID(\"SCHEMA\".\"VIEW_NAME_A\"), 0), 3) = 0`

The job was built from a  DB2 for Z/OS connection --> Connected Data object --> Data Refinery Flow where once the flow looked good, it was saved and then a job was created.  Which failed on the execution.  SCHEMA.VIEW_NAME_A  is a view built of a complex query joining two or more tables together.

I have another data refinery flow for a simpler view table, where it's job (created the same way) works successfully. The query for this view is only one table.

I don't quite understand why Watson Studio built this query for the job run with this WHERE statement and I can't find anything about it.

Someone have an idea on how to fix or workaround this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Watson Studio extracts the source data using multiple queries that partition the data, and that WHERE clause came from its partitioning algorithm.  Apparently its partitioning strategy for z/OS does not work properly when the source is a complex view.  I apologize for the inconvenience and cannot think of a suitable workaround.  We will fix the issue as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you.   I've been thinking on a workaround .. and that would be a rstudio.     using the ibmdbR for zos connection .. following by sql then store in object store. My native R example says it should work